# Drop down, results table not showing Mysql php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Trying to get the results from the Mysql to show up on the web page.
The process is that the user would select a make of a car and then it will show just that make in a table. 
I've been trying different things but I cant seem to get it to show the results. As soon as I get rid of the WHERE statement in the sql query it shows all the cars/makes. I think the problem is in the sql statement or the if.

This is what I've got so far.

```
       <HTML > 

          <head> 
            <title>Inventory</title> 

          </head> 
          <body>


          <form method="get" action="TaskC.php">
                Please select a make:   
                    <select name = "make" >
                    <option value = "All">All</option>
                    <option value = "Toyota">Toyota</option>
                    <option value = "Holden">Holden</option>
                    <option value = "Ford">Ford</option>
                    <option value = "Nissan">Nissan</option>

                </select> <br/>

                <br/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" />

          <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
          <tr>
          <th>Make</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <tr>
          </form>

        <?php 
         //error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        $dbConnect = mysqli_connect('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx')
        or die("<p>The database server is not available.</p>");
        $dbSelect = mysqli_select_db( $dbConnect,'xxxxxxxx_db' )
        or die("<p>The database is not available.</p>");


           $make = $_GET['make'];


        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE make = '" .$make. "'";
         $result = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqli);
        if (isset($_GET['make']) )

        {

        while ($inventory = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
            {

            echo  "<tr>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['make']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['model']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['price']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['quantity']."</td>";

            echo  "</tr>";


            }
            }   
mysqli_close($dbConnect);   
            ?>

        </body> 

        </HTML>
```

Hope you can help.
Thanks

Comment: try this $sqli = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE make = ' ".$make." ' ";

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the query. It should be -

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE make = '" .$make. "'";
```

**Edit**

```
if (isset($_GET['make']) ){
    $make = $_GET['make'];


        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE make = '" .$make. "'";
         $result = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqli);


        while ($inventory = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
            {

            echo  "<tr>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['make']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['model']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['price']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$inventory['quantity']."</td>";

            echo  "</tr>";


        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix up. But its still not showing the make of the car(s).